# Simple Wordpress RewriteRule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm facing a wordpress / htaccess problem. This should be really simple, but it's not working and I'm getting frustrated.

My site handles permalinks this way: `http://www.my-site.com/articles/category/title`

Now, there is a category I called 'closeup' for which I don't want the URL to show 'article'. So I would like to access content from

`http://www.my-site.com/articles/closeup/childCategory/title`

with an URL like this

`http://www.my-site.com/closeup/childCategory/`

I already wrote a page that handles the child category showing all articles on the same page.

So I wrote an htaccess rewrite rule as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^closeup/(.*) articles/closeup/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tested the htaccess online on a website which allowed me to test my htaccess rules, and it works fine there, but not on my blog. Any tip?

So the whole htaccess is:

```
# BEGIN BS

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^closeup/(.*) articles/closeup/$1
</IfModule>

# END BS

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Where is this line in relation to the other wordpress-provided lines in your htaccess? can we see the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this above your # Begin Wordpress block, it should solve the problem:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^closeup/(.*) index.php/articles/closeup/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

### Background:

ReweriteRule is doing what you expect, it's Wordpress that can't find the page. To find the post based on the permalink, Wordpress uses either

```
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
```

or

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

In your case, even after the RewrtieRule the URL appears as

```
http://www.my-site.com/closeup/childCategory/
```

Wordpress uses `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (closeup/childCategory/) to parse the permalink and returns a 404.

If you use RewriteRule to pass the desired path after index.php

```
http://www.my-site.com/index.php?/articles/closeup/childCategory/
```

Wordpress will find your path info (because it tries `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` first) so the  permalink will be `articles/closeup/childCategory/`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Wordpress's custom taxonomy capability instead? Create a page/post type of "closeup."